# Azure VM: After creating VHD URI, Public IP address, Virtual network/subnet and DNS name got deleted

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, vhd

I tried to create VHD and it got created URI for VHD. After VHD creation done, the system got auto shutdown once after shutdown, I intentionally stopped VM.

After few minutes, I tried to re-start the VM but from that time I am not able to connect to that machine and **Public IP address, Virtual network/subnet and DNS names** started showing empty.

[image]

I need someone who can make my VM back.

**Edited**
[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question, but a sysadmin one.

Comment: What do you mean "After VHD creation done, the system got auto shutdown once after shutdown"? And how do you create the VHD?

Comment: @CharlesXu, I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/download-vhd to create VHD. I just did steps at VM side after that it started giving issues.

Comment: Do you try to cancel the URL?

Comment: @CharlesXu, there is no cancel option. let me screenshot you that VHD blade.

Comment: did you capture the vm?

Comment: There is onw point that you should pay attention to. The process of generalizing a VM is not reversible and the VM cannot be restarted. See [Generalize the Windows VM using Sysprep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource#generalize-the-windows-vm-using-sysprep).

Comment: what are the next steps then? I really need that VM back :-(

Comment: You can create a new VM from the VHD file. The system will not change.

Comment: yes, let me try that but not sure. I am able to do that or not. Thank you :-)

Comment: it wont work unless you sysprepped the vm

Comment: I did sysprepped. I guess that step got covered in the link which I followed

Comment: then you need to read what you are doing. docs clearly mention that

Comment: @Ramakrishna Do you solve the problem?

Comment: Nope, I am not able to get back that VM :-(. I tried doing everything manually again.

Answer (score 1):

in this case this was due to the OP capturing the VM. this is the expected behavior.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource#generalize-the-windows-vm-using-sysprep

Comment: it's bad. What are the steps for me to revert and get back my machine?

Comment: there are none. if you did sysprep the vm, create new vm from the image.